# Nilradical in an Artinian ring

Tags: ideals, nilpotence, nilpotent-groups, artinian

I am reading a book that suggests to find what $N(R)$ is - the nilradical of $R$ where $R$ is Artinian you just need to find a nilpotent ideal $I $ of $R$ and then show that $R/I $ has no nonzero nilpotents. Is this enough to show that $I=N(R)$?

I’m not sure why if so.

I know that in an Artinian ring is the largest nilpotent ideal of $R$ and I know that $N(R)$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R$ and $R/N(R)$ has no nil ideals. But could we have another nilpotent of ideal of $R$, say $J$ with $R/J$ having no nil ideals with $J \neq N(R)$?

Comment: If you are assuming commutativity, which seems to be the case, please edit the assumption in.  I say it seems to be the case because "nilradical" usually means the set of nilpotent elements, which isn't always an ideal without commutativity. If you mean something else, you'd need to explain.  There are several notions of nilradical for noncommutative rings.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the possibility of a $J$ such as you ask about, show two things:

a) Every nilpotent ideal $J$ of $R$ is contained in $N(R)$.

[So that leaves only the possibility $J \subsetneq N(R)$ if we assume $J \neq N(R)$.]

b) If $J \subsetneq N(R)$, then $R/J$ does contain nilpotent elements / a nil ideal.

Comment: Why then does $R/J$ contain nilpotent elements? Would it be a nilpotent element from $N(R)/J$?